# Solution of equations

Tags: number-theory

Consider the following system of equivalences of integers.
$$x \equiv 2 ~~\text{mod} ~~ 15$$
$$x \equiv 4 ~~\text{mod} ~~ 21$$
We need to find the number of solutions in $x$, where $1 \lt x \lt 315$, to the above system of equivalences. Is there any general method for solving this kind of problems.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 6):

$x\equiv2\pmod{15}\implies x\equiv2\pmod3$

and $x\equiv4\pmod{21} \implies x\equiv1\pmod3$

So, we need $2\equiv1\pmod 3$ which is impossible , hence there is no solution.

---

Alternatively, $x=15a+2=21b+4$ where $a,b$ are any integers

So, $15a-21b=4-2$

$\implies 3(5a-7b)=2$ which is impossible as the left hand side is divisible by $3$ unlike the right hand side , hence there is no solution.

Comment: Also check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem for $15a\equiv2\pmod {21}$ or $21b\equiv -2\pmod {15}$

Answer (score 2):

This system of congruences is equivalent to
$$ x \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$$
$$ x\equiv 2 \pmod{5}$$
$$ x\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$ x\equiv 4 \pmod{7}.$$
Note that the 1st and third congruences yield a contradiction, hence there is no solution.